# Remove duplicate row where all the columns are the same from data frame

Tags: r

I want to remove duplicated row: the first column C1 can be repetitive but if all others columns are the same as C2=C3=C4=C5 i need to keep only one copy :

example:

```
C1        C2          C3   C4   C5
7163003  17/09/2008   GE    A   45
7163003  17/09/2008   GE    A   45
7163003  08/06/2009   GE    B   50
7163003  22/12/2011   GE    C   45
```

Results:

```
C1        C2          C3   C4   C5
7163003  17/09/2008   GE    A   45
7163003  08/06/2009   GE    B   50
7163003  22/12/2011   GE    C   45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` solution using `distinct`:

```
library(dplyr)

distinct(df)  

       C1         C2 C3 C4 C5
1 7163003 17/09/2008 GE  A 45
2 7163003 08/06/2009 GE  B 50
3 7163003 22/12/2011 GE  C 45
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mydata<-data.frame(C1=c(LETTERS,LETTERS),C2=c(LETTERS,LETTERS),C3=c(LETTERS,LETTERS),C4=c(LETTERS,LETTERS),C5=c(LETTERS,LETTERS))
mydata
mydata[!duplicated(mydata$C1),]
```